# magento 2 custom calendar instead of core calendar

Tags: magento2, ui-form, datepicker, calendar

I want to create jalaali calendar (persian calendar) instead of magento 
core calendar for admin and front pages .

for this purpose I've added these lines to my requirejs-config in my module :

```
   'map': {
       '*': {
          'mage/calendar' : 'MyNamespace_MyModule/js/persian_calendar',
         'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/date' : 'MyNamespace_MyModule/js/form/element/date_form'

        }
    }
```

persian date and gregorian date are completely different and they have different years , months and days name . I want to show persian date to user but save date as gregorian format to database .

for sending gregorian date to server I changed **onShiftedValueChange** 
 function , I do this in my custom date_form :

```
onShiftedValueChange: function (shiftedValue) {
        var value,
            formattedValue,
            formattedValueUTC,
            momentValue;

        // this is very simple code that check if selected date is gregorian date or persian date  
        var englishYears = ["2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022", "2023", "2024", "2025", "2026",
            "2027", "2028", "2029", "2030", "۲۰۱۸", "۲۰۱۹", "۲۰۲۰", "۲۰۲۱", "۲۰۲۲", "۲۰۲۳", "۲۰۲۴",
            "۲۰۲۵", "۲۰۲۶", "۲۰۲۷", "۲۰۲۸", "۲۰۲۹", "۲۰۳۰"];
        var englishDate = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            if (shiftedValue.indexOf(englishYears[i]) > -1) {
                englishDate = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (shiftedValue) {

            // if selected date was persian,I converted it to equivalent gregorian format, for converting dates I used https://github.com/jalaali/moment-jalaali library 
            if (!englishDate) { 
                shiftedValue = jMoment.from(shiftedValue, 'fa', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm').format(this.pickerDateTimeFormat);
            }

            // the rest codes are for magento itself
            momentValue = moment(shiftedValue, this.pickerDateTimeFormat);
            if (this.options.showsTime) {
                formattedValue = moment(momentValue).format(this.timezoneFormat);
                formattedValueUTC = moment.tz(formattedValue, this.storeTimeZone).tz('UTC');
                value = this.outputDateTimeToISO ?
                    formattedValueUTC.toISOString() :
                    formattedValueUTC.format(this.outputDateTimeFormat);
            } else {
                value = momentValue.format(this.outputDateFormat);
            }
        } else {
            value = '';
        }

        if (value !== this.value()) {
            this.value(value);
        }
    }
```

by these code equivalent gregorian date was sent to server correctly , but 
when I checking the value stored in database it's completely different and invalid , for example I sent this value : **4/14/2019 5:30 am** , but magento convert it to : **0010-08-10 05:30:00** !!

I think maybe the format date in my custom date_form is different from format date in magento form php code , cause this problem , because when I changed this.outputDateTimeFormat parameter to for example : "YYYY/DD/MM HH:mm" , stored value was changed and it got valid format value ( for example : "2023-08-10 05:30:00"  ) , but still it has different value from the value has sent and they aren't equivalent.

I don't know where magento check input date and change it to incorrect value .

Does anybody know where magento check date inputes and changing them ?
Or 
Does anyone have a completely different idea for this purpose ?

Comment: can you share your whole code for sending date to the server

Comment: @magefms  thanks for reply , I changed the question and added some changes to it , please check it again .

Comment: `shiftedValue = jMoment.from(shiftedValue, 'fa', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm').format(this.pickerDateTimeFormat);` or `shiftedValue = jMoment.from(shiftedValue, 'fa', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm').format(this.pickerDateTimeFormat);`?

Comment: @magefms shiftedValue = jMoment.from(shiftedValue, 'fa', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm').format(this.pickerDateTimeFormat);  because  calendar UI format date is : 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'  . this part works correctly and it convert persain date to valid gregorian date .

Comment: @magefms  , when I check console when sending to server it still has correct gregorian value , but stored value in database is different later.

Comment: I think the date that was passed to db is the date from the date time picker

Comment: maybe check some methods in your date.js that fetches the date time picker and change its format and check if the format saved in the database is changed also

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it might work:

```
onShiftedValueChange: function (shiftedValue) {
            var value,
                formattedValue,
                formattedValueUTC,
                momentValue;

            // this is very simple code that check if selected date is gregorian date or persian date
            var englishYears = ["2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022", "2023", "2024", "2025", "2026",
                "2027", "2028", "2029", "2030", "۲۰۱۸", "۲۰۱۹", "۲۰۲۰", "۲۰۲۱", "۲۰۲۲", "۲۰۲۳", "۲۰۲۴",
                "۲۰۲۵", "۲۰۲۶", "۲۰۲۷", "۲۰۲۸", "۲۰۲۹", "۲۰۳۰"];
            var englishDate = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                if (shiftedValue.indexOf(englishYears[i]) > -1) {
                    englishDate = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (shiftedValue) {

                // if selected date was persian,I converted it to equivalent gregorian format, for converting dates I used https://github.com/jalaali/moment-jalaali library
                if (!englishDate) {
                    shiftedValueNew = jMoment.from(shiftedValue, 'fa', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm').format(this.pickerDateTimeFormat);
                }

                // the rest codes are for magento itself
                momentValue = moment(shiftedValueNew, this.pickerDateTimeFormat);
                if (this.options.showsTime) {
                    formattedValue = moment(momentValue).format(this.timezoneFormat);
                    formattedValueUTC = moment.tz(formattedValue, this.storeTimeZone).tz('UTC');
                    value = this.outputDateTimeToISO ?
                        formattedValueUTC.toISOString() :
                        formattedValueUTC.format(this.outputDateTimeFormat);
                } else {
                    value = momentValue.format(this.outputDateFormat);
                }
            } else {
                value = '';
            }

            if (value !== this.value()) {
                this.value(value);
            }
        }
```

Comment: it doesn't work , it has same problem .

Comment: I found the problem , when I changed this.outputDateTimeFormat value to : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm" the problem was solved !!!

Comment: That's great :)