# How to modify datepicker input template and js file?

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs, datepicker

I want to change date input data bind attributes and I don't know exactly which file I should overwrite. I changed these files but output is still the same.

```
map: {
    '*': {
        'Magento_Ui/templates/form/element/date': 'Netweb_Shamsi/templates/form/element/date',
        'Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/datepicker' : 'Netweb_Shamsi/js/persian-datepicker'
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please let me know what you want to change in the "data-bind" attribute? On the front end, on which page or in which section you want a datepicker change?

Comment: I want to change every datepicker input in adminhtml. my main reason for that is to add persian calendar to my application

Comment: Please follow the solution from this link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268643/magento-2-custom-calendar-instead-of-core-calendar

Comment: I followed the solution but I'm getting $(...).calendar is not a function error.